# Impact of discrepancy in employment dates on Background Check

Tags: background-check

I had recorded my employment dates for a previous employer as being from January 2015 - March 2015.  However, my actual end date was February 2015 (it was a short term contract).

An agency doing background checks discovered that the actual dates were January to February 2015.  Could this cause an issue in a background check?  I intended it to mean January and February, exclusive of March.

Comment: I have tried to reword your question to make it easier to read.  Please let me know if I have inadvertently changed the context of your question.

Comment: No, I made a mistake and wrote January 2015 - March 2015, Although my contract ended on Feb 2015, (I actually meant to say January and February, exclusive of March.)

Comment: 2015. I don't think anyone is going to make a big deal about it.

Answer (score 3):

Correct it going forwards - but historically, I doubt the month's discrepancy would cause an issue given we're talking about 2014. Unless the work was particularly notable or this was your last position, most employers probably wouldn't bother checking a job you had for a couple of months 3 years ago.

However, as a side note, the more *likely* question I would anticipate is why you only held this position for 2-3 months and not longer.

Comment: This was a contract position for 2 months.I hope this would not cause serious issues.

Comment: I'd suggest marking it on your CV as "contract" to make it obvious that it was specifically a short term role.